# SQL Select Last Date for Each Store

Tags: sql, date, max, teradata

I have a database where each row contains a Site_No, Product_code, Stock_Date and Stock_Qty.  For a single site & product code there can be 20 or so entries, each with different dates.

I need to return ALL Site Numbers, but only the record that contains the newest date.

I've googled, I've read multiple posts on here that seemed to have the same type of query, but haven't been able to get any of the solutions adapted to work for me.  I either end up with only 2 results (the 2 that match the max date) or I still end up with ALL results (all dates and sites)

Using Teradata SQL Assistant

Below is the select statement that will return all entries for Product Code 1234.

```
SELECT Site_No, 
       Product_code, 
       Stock_Date,
       Stock_Qty 
FROM Stock_Levels
where Product_code = 1234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT Site_No, 
       Product_code, 
       Stock_Date,
       Stock_Qty,
       Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Site_No ORDER BY Stock_Date DESC) rn
FROM Stock_Levels
where Product_code = 1234
)A
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, this has worked perfectly - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Teradata there's a nice extension to Standard SQL for filtering the result of a Windowed Aggregate Function, `QUALIFY`:

```
SELECT Site_No, 
       Product_code, 
       Stock_Date,
       Stock_Qty 
FROM Stock_Levels
where Product_code = 1234
QUALIFY
   ROW_NUMBER() 
   OVER (PARTITION BY Site_No           -- for each site
         ORDER BY Stock_Date DESC) = 1  -- get the highest date
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for your time, I tried both answers given and they both work perfectly.